# SharePoint can't write document properties when I upload a word document

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, document, properties

SharePoint is not able to populate document proprieties when I upload word documents to the document library.

Our Sharepoint document library designed in a way when we upload  documents, There is form about title, document name, author etc. We are using a predefined template that Sharepoint can pupulate information form these fields to the document easily.

But I have a couple of users who they are using the same template but sharePoint is not able to populate the form data to the document library and causes workflows to crash.  
I checked the document properties, whether the document is protected or not.

**My question is:** What it could be the cause of issue?

Comment: Have you checked their version of the template they are using to make sure it has not been modified?  Sometimes users can mess things up with a template they save on their machine that is not what SharePoint expects.